# How to display Font Awesome icons in Firefox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, sass, font-face, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using the Font-Awesome-Sass-Rails gem for icon fonts and they display properly in all browsers but Firefox. I'm currently using Cloudfront and Nginx. Here is my CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the answer above does not solve anyone's problem then here is my solution which is working :

```
# Cross domain webfont access
location ~* \.(?:ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$ {
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
expires 1M;
access_log off;
add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Comment: Where do I add this to my rails app?

Comment: in the nginx conf file

Comment: how about in apache?

Answer (score 1):

When I had the same problem I found the only solution which worked for me was setting a header within nginx itself.

```
location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Comment: Do I place this within my server {} brackets?

Comment: I put it in my server {} brackets, restarted nginx, and it's still showing these disfigured boxes instead of the icons.

Comment: Is the location to the font file correct in your CSS file? Can you provide a link to your page?

Comment: I just placed @import "font-awesome"; at the top of my custom.css.scss file. I'm using the font-awesome-sass-rails gem: https://github.com/littlebtc/font-awesome-sass-rails

Comment: The fonts need to be in a folder called `font` on the same level as your CSS folder. If the font files aren't there it won't work. If you have them somewhere else, you need to update the `font-awesome.css` file to change the paths.

Answer (score 1):

examples above did not work, this worked. in nginx config, put if block inside /assets/ rule

```
  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    if ($request_filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)|(svg)|(otf)$) {
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
  }
```